Is there a way to discuss the convergence or divergence of $\sin((3 + \sqrt{2})^n \pi)$?
Is there a way to discuss the convergence or divergence of $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sin((3 + \sqrt{2})^n \pi)$?
If the problem involves a function rather than a sequence, Heine's theorem can be used to show that it does not converge as $x$ approaches infinity.
If $3 + \sqrt{2}$ is replaced with $3 + 2\sqrt{2}$, we can use the fact that $|3 - 2\sqrt{2}| < 1$ and the sum-to-product formulas of trigonometric functions to show that it converges to $0$ as $n$ approaches infinity.
However, for the case in the original problem, I don't have any ideas.

This is essentially a question about the fractional part of $(3+\sqrt2)^n$. I would not expect this to converge, but I don't think any such result has been proved.

I was kind of hoping it would have been $\sin[(3+\color{blue}{2}\sqrt2)^n\pi]$.

It is known that for any algebraic number $a>1$ a necessary condition for the fractional part of $a^n$ to have finitely many limit points is for $a$ to be a Pisot number (all Galois conjugates have modulus strictly less than $1$). This is theorem $5.6.2$ in the monograph by Bertin et others on Pisot and Salem numbers (actually the theorem is if and only if allowing for the existence of a multiplier $\lambda$ st the fractional part of $\lambda a^n$ has finitely many limit points)
Writing $a^n=q_n+e_n$ with $q_n$ positive integer and $0 \le e_n <1$ one has $\sin \pi a^n=(-1)^{q_n}\sin \pi e_n$ so the convergence of $\sin \pi a^n$ implies that $e_n$ can have only finitely many limit points so by the above $a$ must be Pisot and $3+\sqrt 2$ is obviously not, hence the sequence in the OP diverges.

I wanted to write that. But you did it better anyway. +1
